# TTPostController won't rotate

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, three20, autorotate

First, I'm sorry because my English isn't good :) This is my code to create a new TTPostController

```
postController = [[TTPostController alloc] init];
postController.delegate = self;
self.popupViewController = postController;
postController.superController = self;
[postController showInView:self.view animated:YES];
```

It run okay if I don't rotate the device

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBmpn.png

But when I rotated the device, it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt7lq.png

(Sorry i don't have enough reputation to post images)

Does anyone knows how to fix it?

**Edit:**
Problem fixed, I've written my own library like TTPostController :D

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass TTPostController and override the should autorotate method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Eamonn! shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method in subclass is only called when the TTPostController loaded in first time. But when I rotated the device, nothing happens :(